# How can I make a horizontally scrollable div with divs in it?

Tags: php, html, css, scroll

I created a div which contains divs. These divs within the div are images and a bit of text. I want the main div to be scrollable horizontally. The divs within are aligned using inline-block.

When I use

```
overflow-x: scroll;
```

The div gets 2 scroll bars, but only the vertical one works.
When I put in more divs than the width of the main div, these divs get placed in the row below. I want these to be placed next to the other divs, and when they go offpage, you can scroll to get to them.
What can I do to do this?

Div code (I use a database to input the divs, and this works):

```
echo '<div id="indiv">';
            foreach ($result as $pers) {
                $time = date('H:i', strtotime( $pers->tijd ) );
                echo "<div id='imgnaam'>";
                echo "<img id='bigimageind' src=".$pers->img.">";
                echo "<hr>";
                echo "<p id='imgnaam2'>".$time."</p>";
                echo "</div>";
            }    
            echo '</div>';
```

And the CSS:

```
#imgnaam2 {
height: 50px;
width: 200px;
text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 20px;
    background-color: rgba(155, 82, 197, 0.425);
}

#bigimage {
    height: relative;
    width: 20%;
    display: inline-block; 
}

#indiv {
    background-color: rgba(128, 0, 128, 0.432);
    border: 35px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.459);
    overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
#indiv{
 width: max-content !important;
}
```

or this:

```
#indiv{
 width: 100%;
 display: flex;
 flex-flow: row;
 flex-wrap: nowrap;
 overflow: scroll;
}
```

Comment: @Man8zzzzzzzzzDWOMAN You are welcome. Can you mark the answer as well. thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Use overflow

```
.container {
    width: 30em;
    overflow-x: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vzu5f.gif)